# libgdx gwt install error eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, libgdx, installation

I'm trying to make a libgdx Android project work (= build) on Eclipse. It's the project from the book "Libgdx Game Development" : I just opened the GDX set up GUI and created a project named "demo".
I get two errors about GWT in the "Problems" Tab, in the demo-html project :

1. The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint. Fix the build path then try building this project

2.The type com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I have GWT Designer for GPE, Google Plugin for Eclipse and SDKS installed in the plug-in tab (from the Help > Install new Software), so I have no idea why it doesn't work.
All the questions that had those error messages were resolved by downloading the plug-ins I quoted, but in my case, they are downloaded and installed (can't re-install them since it tells me it is already installed) and I hit also already checked for updates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, I tried everything and checked the other answers before posting mine :/ Setting the compiler from Java 1.5 to 1.7 adds one more error, i'll paste it later